# Получить список друзей из таблицы в laravel

Tags: laravel

Есть таблица Users

id = 1, name = Василий

id = 2, name = Андрей

id = 3, name = Петр

И таблица Frends

user_id = 1, frend= 2

user_id = 1, frend= 3

И модели User и Frend

В модели User

```
public function frends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Frend::class);
}
```

Контроллер FrendController

```
public function index()
{
    $users= User::all();
    return view('frends.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Вывожу список

```
@foreach($users as $key => $user)
  ID - {{ $user->id}} = 
    @foreach($user->frends as $key => $item)
       <p>{{ $item->id }},</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Получаю ID - 1 = 2,3

Как получить список друзей Василия виде ID - 1 = Андрей,Петр